# Is there a convention or correct order for chaining constructors?

Tags: java, constructor-chaining

Ive been thinking about this and I've seen different examples on this. Usually I would chain constructors in a upward manner. So if I have 4 different constructors, starting with a default constructor, who calls the constructor where we need to pass in one argument, who calls the constructor where we need 2 arguments to pass in and so on, so we have usable objects, where all the fields hold data.

Is there a different approach to chaining constructor because I couldn't think of another case ? Why would I want my constructor, where I need 3 arguments to pass in, call my constructor where I only need to pass in 2 arguments ?

Comment: On GeeksforGeeks, they show a picture, where constructors are chained in a downward manner. Exactly the opposite of mine, which seems confusing to me.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you provided a link to the article you are mentioning since your question is extremely generic and opinion based (so not a good fit for SO) and it appears that you have a specific case in mind described in this article that "troubles you", yet by failing to providing the reference to this article you can only receive generic or "guess" answers.

Comment: I would not chain constructors but rather let all constructors call the same "base" constructor, that is the one that takes all the arguments. But I would also question if I really need this many constructors.

Answer (score 0):

The Builder pattern works for this scenario. A rough demo could look like this:

```
Dog dog = new DogBuilder().setHeight(10).setWeight(40).setColor(Color.BROWN).build();
```

Each set method returns a reference to the `DogBuilder` instance, with that property set. Calling `.build()` calls a private/package private constructor with all values set.

This is a good article for reference:
https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I think "common sense" best practices are:

- Minimize the number of constructors your class offers (for example by relying on the *Builder* pattern)
- Yes, "upward chaining" where the *n arg* constructor calls an *n+1* constructor (and provides a default argument) is probably the more common (and more useful) style.

But as the last sentence indicates: to a certain degree, this is about "personal" style. Or whatever "style" applies. When your team is used to do things in a different way, and you have hundreds of existing classes following that "special style", then you allow that "team internal" preference to guide your actions.